# Fixing /usr/local/include/string.h on Mac

Tags: c, osx-mavericks

I can no longer compile any C or ruby code, as I have messed up /usr/local/include.

This is the error I get when doing anything involving C, including making a new rails application.

I am certain I have done something with /usr/local/include when I was playing around with C.

I've reinstalled everything a number of times, including XCode and Command Line Tools.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Would be much appreciated!

```
*Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies....
Using rake 11.0.1
Using i18n 0.7.0
Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
In file included from generator.c:1:
In file included from ./../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5:
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33:
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:51:
/usr/local/include/string.h:44:1: error: unknown type name '__BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD'
__BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD
^
/usr/local/include/string.h:46:1: error: expected identifier or '('
extern void *memcpy (void *__restrict __dest, const void *__restrict __src,
^
/usr/local/include/string.h:51:6: error: expected function body after function declarator
     __THROW __nonnull ((1, 2));
     ^*
```

Comment: If it helps, I don't even have `/usr/local/include` (OS X 10.11.3 with Xcode 7.2.1). You might be able to just nuke that directory, depending on what you have installed.

Comment: For the C command line tools, the default header search path is `Applications/Xcode.app/.../include`. In other words, the system headers are inside the Xcode app itself, not in `/usr/local/include`. Can't say what Ruby does.

Comment: How about restoring from your Time Machine backup?

Comment: I ended up reinstalling OS X - lesson learned - don't play around with those files!